# MySQL query with multiple 'OR' statements

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a query, that I have tested outside of PHP directly on SQL and still getting the same problem

The idea being that $currentArtist is sent through using the GET method, where this value matches the value in the `event_artist` columns the information is displayed.

```
SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            `".DBN."`.`events`
        WHERE
            `event_artist1` OR `event_artist2` OR `event_artist3` = '".$currentArtist."'

    ";
```

The problem I have is that it is completely ignoring the `WHERE` part of the query. It just returns the complete table results and not the results that match `$currentArtist`.

I have tested `$currentArtist` and it works fine. I'm at a loss as to how to get the complete statement to work.

I've tried surrounding the `OR` statements in brackets as in:

```
(`event_artist1` OR `event_artist2`...) = '".$currentArtist."'
```

This only returns a result if the `$currentArtist` is equal to "1" being the first person in the Artists table where their information is stored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM events e
 WHERE '$currentArtist' IN (e.event_artist1,e.event_artist2,e.event_artist3);
```

Comment: interesting, I've never tried putting columns in an `IN` clause, only constants...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT e.*` if you've assigned `e` for events? Or is that not required for a single table select?

Comment: It's not required, but it is good practice. Better practice is naming all required columns.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks for your help. I'm fairly new to MySql and PHP so I'm currently on the baby steps of the language, do you possibly know of a good tutorial to help me better understand the statement you have done above?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM `".DBN."`.`events` WHERE
            `event_artist1`= '".$currentArtist."' OR `event_artist2`= '".$currentArtist."' OR `event_artist3` = '".$currentArtist."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `".DBN."`.`events`
WHERE `event_artist1` = '".$currentArtist."' 
OR `event_artist2` = '".$currentArtist."' 
OR `event_artist3` = '".$currentArtist."'
";
```

Hope this helps.